# xts replace a value in a certain column by date

Tags: r, xts

I'm struggling with replacing a value within an xts object. Here's a sample:

```
dates <- as.Date(c("1996-08-02","1996-08-05", "1996-08-06"))
test <- xts(rep(1,3), order.by = dates)
names(test) <- "Stock1"
test$CASH <- NA #adding a cash position to portfolio
test["1996-08-02"]$CASH <- 1
```

With this last line, I get the following warning message:

```
In NextMethod(.Generic) :
number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

I'm sure there's something I'm doing wrong, but I haven't found a solution, as similar issues are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution right here:

[XTS replacement error NextMethod(.Generic) : number of items to replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23768007/xts-replacement-error-nextmethod-generic-number-of-items-to-replace)

I needed to add a comma :

```
test["1996-08-02",]$CASH <- 1
# works!
```

Comment: You can save the additional function call by using: `test["1996-08-02", "CASH"] <- 1`.

Comment: @DanielMc you might want to accept your answer (green tick) as it solved your problem